# File uploads in Elm using pre-signed URIs to S3

Tags: haskell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, elm

Is there an Elm library that does CORS signed uploads to AWS S3? Motivation is you want media uploads to go straight to your S3 buckets, not hammer your web/app server.

Here is how you do it [over curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044151/how-to-generate-a-temporary-url-to-upload-file-to-amazon-s3-with-boto-library?rq=1).

One answer on doing [regular file uploads in Elm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329962/file-upload-in-elm).

Answer on how to do it [with JQuery File Upload](http://pjambet.github.io/blog/direct-upload-to-s3/).

Also looking for a Haskell library on the server side to do the signing, as it doesn't seem that Amazonka's S3 does the CORS signing yet. Looks like I might have to FFI or shell out for that part just to get going.

Comment: I would recommend splitting these into two separate questions.

Comment: Translating the Python Boto S3 URI signing logic into Haskell isn't that big of a deal. Might even be quicker to code than shelling out to Boto.

Answer (score 1):

Since the 0.17.0 update, this is pretty straightforward. In fact, the documentation has an example that does a CORS post in it.

http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-http/3.0.1/Http

... search for `corsPost`