# elm: read file content

Tags: xml, file, elm

Is there a way to read a file in `elm`?

I want to have an `xml` settings file where I will keep different settings and read it with elm (I've seen this [parser](https://github.com/toburger/elm-xml-parser), but it expects the `xml` content, not path). I don't want to use ports and these stuff. I need to apply some transformations to this `xml` because I will have more sets of values (staging and production) and I will need to generate an artefact for each value (I'm using `TFS` for this).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Upload in Elm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329962/file-upload-in-elm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of today (`0.18.0`), officially Elm does not support [File API](http://File%20API) and other file-related APIs.

You can perform I/O only through WebSockets or over HTTP.

Anything else is covered by [ports.](http://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/javascript.html)

Comment: Is something planned? Is there a roadmap for this feature?

Answer (score 2):

This [library](https://github.com/simonh1000/file-reader) provides access to the filereader API. It is only on github because, as it uses native code, it cannot be published on elm-package.

However if you want to use it with xml you might be best using ports anyway, because then you could get javascripts xml parsing too, which will otherwise be a challenge in Elm too.